# Is there an aws provided feature to automatically add private dns to route53

Tags: amazon-web-services, dns, amazon-route53

We have a vpc in aws, it there some feature provided by aws to automatically add private DNS to route53 when manually launch an instance.

Answer (score 1):

If you have installed boto, you can add / update DNS settings like this:

```
DNS_ADDRESS="`ec2metadata | grep 'public-hostname:' | cut -d ' ' -f 2`"
/usr/local/bin/route53 change_record <Hosted zone ID> foo.bar.com. CNAME $DNS_ADDRESS 300
```

`DNS_ADDRESS` is the AWS DNS name of the instance such as *ec2-1-2-3-4.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com*

The second line creates a CNAME with 5min TTL. You need to add the hosted zone ID of the domain you want to change.

If you put this snippet into `/etc/rc.local`, the instance will automatically update / create the CNAME when it's booting.

I'm not sure what you mean with "private" DNS. Route53 provides a (public) DNS service. However, if your instances are inside a VPC there's no harm to make the DNS entries public, since no one can access them anyway.

Comment: Route 53 allows you to create VPC specific zones. These zones are "private" in that only instances in that VPC can see those records. I don't believe boto has been updated to support private DNS

Answer (score 1):

Sample Script:

```
/usr/local/bin/route53 change_record $Hosted_zone_ID $DNS-Name A $IP 300
```

`$Hosted_zone_ID`, `$DNS-Name`, `$IP` are place holders. Replace them with actual values to run script

Answer (score 0):

There is no feature built-in to AWS that does this automatically, but AWS provides a feature that allows you to customize all kinds of things using simple workflows and a bit of Javascript.

For example, we use an auto scaling group to launch instances as needed, and we have used [this blog article](https://objectpartners.com/2015/07/07/aws-tricks-updating-route53-dns-for-autoscalinggroup-using-lambda/) as a sample of how to set up an AWS Lambda function that receives SNS notifications from the auto scaling group when an instance goes up and down, and adds a custom DNS name to the route 53 zone. It should be pretty straight forward to customize it for your needs.