# AWS Route 53 do I need two hosted zons one form domain with WWW and another wihtout?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-route53

I have problem with proper configuration of route 53.

I configured it as described here [do I need route53 to bind domain to ec2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24937666/do-i-need-route53-to-bind-domain-to-ec2) and for mydomain.com it works, but for www.mydomain.com not.

I created two hosted zones, is it the right way, or it is possible to be done with one configuration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only need to use one hosted zone for mydomain.com and just make sure that you add a record set of type `CNAME` with name set to `www.mydomain.com` and value `mydomain.com`. You can find more details in [Creating and deleting resource record sets](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/RRSchanges_console.html) of the AWS documentation

Comment: Thanks! I will accept this answer if you only correct mistake: name should be set to www.mydomain.com and value domain.com not the opposit.